# How to check if a date has passed in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm reading the date expires cookie (2 hours) from database, and I need to check if this date has passed. What's the best way to do this?

For example:

```
public bool HasExpired(DateTime now)
{
    string expires = ReadDateFromDataBase(); // output example: 21/10/2011 21:31:00
    DateTime Expires = DateTime.Parse(expires);
    return HasPassed2hoursFrom(now, Expires);
}
```

I'm looking for ideas as write the `.HasPassed2hoursFrom` method.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
public bool HasPassed2hoursFrom(DateTime fromDate, DateTime expireDate) 
{
    return expireDate - fromDate > TimeSpan.FromHours(2);
}
```

Comment: If the fromDate is 4 hours before the expireDate, this method would return true. i.e. fromDate is: 1/1/1 00:00:01, and expire date is 1/1/1 04:00:01, that method would return true; when it should return false.

Comment: To be honest I'm yet to fully understand the question: he uses expiration date, but them he uses now, but now is coming from the outside only to be passed outside again. Well, kind of a spaghetti code. Bottom line I've just answered to his last request: how to implement a method named `HasPassed2hoursFrom` that receives two parameters. In short just wanted him to understand how easy is to perform operations over DateTime, in conjunction with TimeSpan.

Answer (score 5):

```
bool HasPassed2hoursFrom(DateTime now, DateTime expires)
{
    return (now - expires).TotalHours >= 2;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Periodically check the date and see if `now.CompareTo(expires) > 0`

Comment: I like this function, but it's only part of an answer

Answer (score 4):

```
public bool HasExpired(DateTime now)
{
    string expires = ReadDateFromDataBase(); // output example: 21/10/2011 21:31:00
    DateTime Expires = DateTime.Parse(expires);
    return now.CompareTo(Expires.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))) > 0;
}
```

But since DateTime.Now is very fast and you don't need to pass it as function parameter...

```
public bool HasExpired()
{
    string expires = ReadDateFromDataBase(); // output example: 21/10/2011 21:31:00
    DateTime Expires = DateTime.Parse(expires);
    return DateTime.Now.CompareTo(Expires.Add(new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0))) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use operators

```
boolean hasExpired = now >= Expires;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private enum DateComparisonResult
    {
        Earlier = -1,
        Later = 1,
        TheSame = 0
    };

    void comapre()
    {
        DateTime Date1 = new DateTime(2020,10,1);
        DateTime Date2 = new DateTime(2010,10,1);

        DateComparisonResult comparison;
        comparison = (DateComparisonResult)Date1.CompareTo(Date2);
        MessageBox.Show(comparison.ToString());    
    }
    //Output is "later", means date1 is later than date2
```

***To check if date has passed:***

Source:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ata5aya%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396